# Pandas drop rows with identical combination of data in different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the follow df:

```
roles = [("user1", "rol1", "rol2"),
         ("user1", "rol4", "rol1"), 
         ("user3", "rol1", "rol3"), 
         ("user3", "rol1", "rol3"), 
         ("user1", "rol1", "rol3"), 
         ("user1", "rol2", "rol1"), 
         ("user2", "rol5", "rol6"),
         ("user2", "rol6", "rol5"), 
         ("user2", "rol1", "rol3"), 
         ("user3", "rol3", "rol1"), 
         ("user1", "rol1", "rol4"), 
         ("user3", "rol3", "rol1"), 
        ]; 
df = pd.DataFrame(roles, columns=["User", "Rol_1", "Rol_2"])
```

The combinations of columns  `"Rol_1"` and `"Rol_2"` are the same if `("Rol_1", "Rol_2") == ("Rol_2", "Rol_1")` by User. I need to drop rows where the combinations are the same (by User)l;

> i.e. the row where `User = "user1" and (Rol_1,Rol_2) = ("rol4","rol1")` must be dropped because exists `(Rol_1,Rol_2) = ("rol1","rol4")` for the same user.

The expected result of this example would be:

```
rolexp = [("user1", "rol1", "rol2"),
          ("user1", "rol4", "rol1"), 
          ("user1", "rol1", "rol3"), 
          ("user2", "rol5", "rol6"),
          ("user2", "rol1", "rol3"), 
          ("user3", "rol1", "rol3"), 
         ]; 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rolexp, columns=["User", "Rol_1", "Rol_2"])
```

Is it possible to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If either of the combination can be retained(`rol1  rol4` instead of `rol4  rol1`) , this can be done by using `np.sort` on `axis=1` and `drop_duplicates`;

```
cols = ['Rol_1','Rol_2']
u = df.assign(**pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[cols],axis=1),columns=cols,index=df.index))
out = u.drop_duplicates(['User']+cols).sort_values("User")
```

---

```
print(out)

    User Rol_1 Rol_2
0  user1  rol1  rol2
1  user1  rol1  rol4
4  user1  rol1  rol3
6  user2  rol5  rol6
8  user2  rol1  rol3
2  user3  rol1  rol3
```

Comment: This solution works fine! Is better to add a new column. Thanks!!

Comment: @dan the expected output didnot have new columns, however keeping similar logic, I will leave it upto you, look at `df.duplicated`

Comment: Also `df.join` with `lsuffix` and `drop_duplicates`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a new column with a set of all the roles by each row, then drop duplicates.

```
df['all_roles'] = df.drop(columns='User').apply(
    lambda x: ', '.join(sorted(list(set(x)))), axis=1)
df.drop_duplicates(['User', 'all_roles'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output

```
    User Rol_1 Rol_2   all_roles
0  user1  rol1  rol2  rol1, rol2
1  user1  rol4  rol1  rol1, rol4
2  user3  rol1  rol3  rol1, rol3
4  user1  rol1  rol3  rol1, rol3
6  user2  rol5  rol6  rol5, rol6
8  user2  rol1  rol3  rol1, rol3
```